# Trying to make popup window with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make popup window using react, but when I click the button, there is only thin white line across the screen. Why is that happen?

[image: screen]

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/2095/Messenger-client?file=/src/components/searchPanel/searchPanel.js

Comment: Can you also share screenPanel.css

Comment: Could you please post your working code on snack alongwith all dependencies

Comment: .search-input{
  width: 50rem;
}

.modal {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.modal > .header {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.modal > .content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
.modal > .actions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

Comment: Please create a sample on codesandbox or somewhere else where its easy to reproduce the issue

Comment: A codesandbox example would really help but have you tried adding a fixed height to your .modal class?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please take a look at these helpful introductions so you can write effective questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  It will be a lot easier for folks to help you out if you embed code and a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Here's codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/2095/Messenger-client?file=/src/components/searchPanel/searchPanel.js

Comment: Oh! I see you are using reactjs-popup. I looked quicly at the sandbox, and if I remove the className "modal" of your div inside the popup, it is working well. So just remove to modal related css, and replace it for you own css.

Answer (score 0):

You did not sent a codesandbox of your html and css so it's hard to say your errors. If I understand correctly, you are using your own css for the pop up? If it is the case, it is probably just your css that is the problem.

If you want to have a popup or modal quickly with nice style and customizable, you can use a library. Here is a list of different libraries you could use:

- [reactjs-popup](https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup)
- [reactjs-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)
- [material-ui-modal](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/)
- [using bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

Edit: Since you posted your code sandbox, I see you are using reactjs-popup. It seems that the css you provided to the child inside the popup component is not valid. Just remove the css related to "modal" and replace it to your own. I tried it and it shows correctly.

Comment: It helped! Thanks a lot!